# JSON database in Android

Tags: android, database, json

I have a database format JSON (for example, data.json), it is possible to add this file in the application and use as a local database? When developing an application to add the file, and when removing applications from your device, removing it along with the application.

Comment: and why you want to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a folder named "raw" in /res/ and then you can access it at R.raw.data.

Pretty sure since it's within the context of your app, if the app is removed the data is as well.

Comment: good luck writting there.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Could not tell the example code

Comment: Oh, never mind. I didn't realize that you couldn't write to raw files.